# How to replace characters in a date string

Tags: javascript

Write a function `normalize`, that replaces '-' with '/' in a date string.

Example: `normalize('20-05-2017')` should return `'20/05/2017'`.

I have tried this:

```
let d = new Date('27-11-2021');

function normalize(session){    
     let normal = d.replace('-','/');
     
     return (session);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Naman! Why do you return the `session` variable in the `normalize` function? And check the `d` variable -> it should not be used inside the function, if you have the `session` parameter

Comment: I have kept d variable inside function and now also it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

As you are being asked to pass a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) representation of a date to the `normalize` function, you can use [String.prototype.replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) to replace each `-` with `/` in the string.

For this problem, there does not appear to be a need to parse the string as an actual javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

```js
// Write a function normalize, that replaces '-' with '/' in a date string.
// Example: normalize('20-05-2017') should return '20/05/2017'.
function normalize(stringDate) {
  const normal = stringDate.replaceAll('-', '/');
  return normal;
}

const result = normalize('20-05-2017')
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can you explain me the return property??

Comment: It is returning the output of `String.prototype.replaceAll()` method on the normalize 
 function's parameter `stringDate`. You can do it in 2 steps by creating a variable first, then returning that variable from the function instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try This or Use replaceAll instead of replace function because in new ES replaceAll is working.

```
let date = normalize('20-05-2017');
console.log('date: ',date);

function normalize(date){
    return (date.replace(/-/g,'/'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the date is invalid for some reason. In the constructor, you cannot pass in `27-8-2021`. So for example, you can go this way.

```js
let d = new Date();

d.toLocaleDateString() // returns '8/27/2021'
d.toLocaleDateString('en-in') // returns '27/8/2021'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function normalize(Date){    
    let normal = Date.replace('-','/');
    let norm2= normal.replace('-','/');
    return norm2;
}

let Date = '27-11-2021';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).